# Send DMs to a specific role members in Discord

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, message, roles

I'm trying to create a bot for my own server that sends out DMs to specific role members. I'm thinking about a command like `!send @Members 'good day'` perhaps. But most importantly, I need to collect the data of their replies. It doesn't matter so much what they replied, I just need to know if they replied or not. And it should be with a list of usernames.

A return like this:

100 members of the X role were sent DMs.
48 users replied - (user list)
50 users not replied - (user list)
2 messages couldn't be delivered (user list)

Is this achievable with a Discord bot? Or in any other ways?
I've found some similar questions here but the codes in there were very old, like posted 2-3 years ago. So much changed ever since, I can't even write an example from a Google search.

So basically I need a code for sending out the DMs and another one for reports I guess.

Comment: I think you can make this command using `message.guild.members.fetch` then do a forloop

Comment: This is doable, but a bad idea. See [Rate Limits](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits). Mass-DMing users can be seen as spam or abuse, and is pretty much a sure-fire way to get application-banned.

Comment: Why not ping the role, that's why they exist. There's always better alternatives than to mass X.

Comment: Yeah the limits, probable scam thing and closed DMs for privacy made me unfollow my quest here. Thank you very much guys. (: My main goal with this was to see who is bot account and who is genuine human. Let them in without captcha already, so the ones failed to reply to a message within 7 days, was going to be kicked. (:

Comment: Instead, I chose the easier path and created a new role, pinged everyone, and announced that if they fail the get this role in a week, they'll be kicked. :D let's see how it goes. Thanks again guys, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Something that I'd do is loop through all the members and check if they have the role, although I don't suggest giving too many people the role as it could rate limit your bot.

Here's an example:

```js
guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
    if (member.roles.cache.has("RoleID")) member.send("Hello")
});
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be complete. The snippet above doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros My bad, I got distracted and forgot to complete the snippet. I've edited the answer, sorry.